# pimcore-install command getting stuck at 0% in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pimcore

`./vedor/bin/pimcore-install` command getting stuck at 0% in ubuntu 20.04.

Sometimes it goes to 18% and stuck.

I am not able to solve it.

In the error log it show some symfony related warning.

```
[2021-08-12T10:44:18.202806+05:30] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\AuthenticationProviderDecorator" class implements "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\AuthenticationProviderInterface" that is deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use the new authenticator system instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: The \"Scheb\\TwoFactorBundle\\Security\\Authentication\\Provider\\AuthenticationProviderDecorator\" class implements \"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Provider\\AuthenticationProviderInterface\" that is deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use the new authenticator system instead. at /var/www/pimcore/project1/vendor/symfony/error-handler/DebugClassLoader.php:390)"} []
[2021-08-12T10:44:18.202828+05:30] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Since symfony/event-dispatcher 5.1: Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\LegacyEventDispatcherProxy is deprecated, use the event dispatcher without the proxy. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since symfony/event-dispatcher 5.1: Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\LegacyEventDispatcherProxy is deprecated, use the event dispatcher without the proxy. at /var/www/pimcore/project1/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/LegacyEventDispatcherProxy.php:16)"} []
[2021-08-12T10:44:18.416854+05:30] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Since symfony/event-dispatcher 5.1: Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\LegacyEventDispatcherProxy is deprecated, use the event dispatcher without the proxy. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since symfony/event-dispatcher 5.1: Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\LegacyEventDispatcherProxy is deprecated, use the event dispatcher without the proxy. at /var/www/pimcore/project1/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/LegacyEventDispatcherProxy.php:16)"} []
[2021-08-12T10:44:18.486394+05:30] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT id FROM assets LIMIT 1 [] []
```

[image]

can anyone help. thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need help, why not show these error messages?

Comment: updated with the dev.log

Comment: drop your database and create again. I had had this issue when some data has been previously setup and the process does not completed it.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I'm having a same issue where the process simply doesn't start and stays stuck at 0%.

Comment: yes, the best thing would be install a fresh version and create new DB and install it once. if it is not installed at first then you have to delete the DB and create again, then try installing. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be - create a user new for mysql and use that user for your project. Also as @Christian said if the setup process failed once then you have to drop the database and create again. And then repeat the installation process again.